# Backend of html form

Tags: php, forms

I need help on the backend of my html form. What I want to do is of course take the information that the user inputted on the html page that included the actual form. The page is interpreting the data in php and I would like it to send an email to myself with the information gathered. I have all of the security measures in place and as far as I can tell ,it should work. But for some reason it is not...It is giving me a syntax error on line 20. I will provide the full code of the php file that gathers the user information. I don't think I need to post the actual html form, but if it is requested I will post that as well. Thanks for the help.

```
 <?php
  require_once('recaptchalib.php');
  $privatekey = "aFakePrivateKey";
  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

  if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
    die ("The CAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again.");
  } else {





if(isset($_POST['eadrr'])) {

    $email_to = "blank@blank.com";
    $email_subject = "Customer Support";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['inquire']) ||
        !isset($_POST['eadrr']) ||
        !isset($_POST['mess'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $type = $_POST['inquire']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['eadrr']; // required
    $comments = $_POST['mess']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($comments) < 5) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Type of Inquiry: ".clean_string($type)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

echo 'Thank you for your message. Based on the type of inquiry we may respond within a week.';

}


  }
?>
```

Error Message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/a6675286/public_html/verify.php  on line 20

Comment: Can you show the error message you're getting?

Comment: Line 20 in your posted code is `$email_to = ...`. There's no syntax error on that line. Can you please indicate to us, in some fashion, the actual line with the syntax error?

Comment: That is honestly the error php is giving me, now you understand why I am confused

Comment: Is the above code the exact code for verify.php? There are no syntax errors in the provided code, per an IDE and per execution (I even created a fake "recaptchalib.php/`recaptcha_check_anser`" to test).

Comment: I suggest you put your functions together somewhere on top (or close to) of your file, instead of random locations in your code. (it won't solve your error, but it will make code more readable)

Comment: That is the exact code and for some reason it is not working on my server. Could it be an issue with my web host?

Comment: "Syntax error" means something is very wrong somewhere in your source code.

Comment: @Jocelyn And yet, the source code worked fine for newfurniturey.

Comment: @Palladium Yes that is why I am so confused.

Comment: My web host is running php vers. 5.2.* could that be the issue?

Comment: @Palladium: that's right, I checked it too! Twisterz: I don't think it is the cause.

Comment: So any idea on what the cause could be?

Comment: None whatsoever. If it's not in your source code then it's either there's actually a (for lack of a better word) runtime error elsewhere that's somehow messing with your backend (which'll take forever and a day to find), or a problem with your server (which we have no power to fix).

Comment: Oh well, I guess I'll see what I can find on my own. At least I know my source code is fine though. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
died('We are sorry, but ...
```

tp this:

```
die('We are sorry, but you cannot spell
```

Unless of course you actually wrote a function called died()...